# Get-ADUser and issue with nested groups

Tags: powershell

When I run the command below on a nested group, I get the error below.

```
$properties = 'SamAccountName','GivenName'
(Get-ADGroup -identity $group -properties members).members | Get-ADUser -property $properties | select-object $properties
```

The setup is  such that $group is a parent of all other groups, for example
$group = 'All_USA', there are other groups all under $group such as NY_Group and TX_Group to name a few.

Get-ADUSer cannot find object with identity 'CN=DG NY_Group,OU=Messaging...

This issue only happens where the group is a parent group which has other child groups inside it.

Answer (score 1):

The members from `Get-ADGroup` can also be other groups or computer objects, not only users.

Try

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive |
    Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' } |
    Get-ADUser |
    Select-Object SamAccountName, GivenName
```

You may want to add switch `-Unique` to the `Select-Object` cmdlet so you don't listy users that were found in nested groups aswell.

<sup>'SamAccountName' and 'GivenName' properties are returned by default with `Get-ADUser`</sup>

Comment: I tried the recommendation above, nothing happens as it doesn't return any details from AD.

Comment: @user3535468 Then please show what is inside `$group` **exactly**